# vundle not working properly with ftplugin

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, vundle, ftplugin

I started to use the ftplugin. This is basically working, except for bundle. If I start gvim with a file that has no specific filetype I can use all my plugins (:VundleInstall lists all the plugins specified in the .vimrc)

But when I open a file with a .cpp type and thus using the *.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim* the only active (shown by :VundleInstall) plugins are the one, specified in the cpp.vim file.

What is my mistake?

Here is my vimrc:

```
syntax on
set nocompatible
set t_Co=256

filetype plugin indent on

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" syntax check during writing
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

....

"swap two panes in an open session
Plugin 'wesQ3/vim-windowswap'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required

....
```

And this is my cpp.vim file:

```
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

"plugin to switch easily between header and source
Plugin 'derekwyatt/vim-fswitch'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required

....
```

I've shortened the mappings, and the long list of plugins by replacing it with the dots(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone gets the same problems:

In this [thread](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/715) you can find the solution.